# Can't run ffmpeg as subprocess in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg

I am trying following code to determine video resolution by running ffmpeg utility as subprocess and gain its output and parse it:

```
IO.popen 'ffmpeg -i ' + path_to_file do |ffmpegIO|
    # my parse goes here
end
```

...but ffmpeg output is still connected to stdout and ffmepgIO.readlines is empty. Are there some special treatment needed for ffmpeg utility? Or are there other way to gain ffmpeg output? 
I tested this code under WinXP and Fedora Linux - results are same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To follow-up on mouviciel's comment, you would need to use something like [popen3](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open3/rdoc/index.html):

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3("ffmpeg", "-i", path_to_file) { |stdin, stdout, stderr|
  # do stuff
}
```

(btw, note that using an array as parameter to popen would be a bit safer, especially if the filename may include spaces or any kind of character that would need to be quoted otherwise)

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg stdout is for media output. For logging information (such as resolution) you have to parse ffmpeg stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do it might be easier to use the [rvideo gem](http://rvideo.rubyforge.org/rdoc/).

For example:

```
video = RVideo::Inspector.new(:file => path_to_file)
video.resolution # => "480x272"
video.width # => 480
video.height # => 272
```

Comment: I am already disappointed in RVideo gem because it doesn't work with ffmpeg. I inspect source code of this gem and founded that it try tu run ffmpeg just as i described and therefore fails.